# É possível substituir certos valores por NA em pandas sem o uso de laços?

Tags: python, pandas, ciência-de-dados

Estava estudando limpeza de dados, e vi que as vezes pode haver valores int em colunas que deveriam ser string e vice versa, então a solução dada pelo autor da publicação que eu estava lendo usa um laço for para substituir os valores para NaN da seguinte maneira.

```
# Detecting numbers 
cnt=0
for row in df['OWN_OCCUPIED']:
    try:
        int(row)
        df.loc[cnt, 'OWN_OCCUPIED']=np.nan
    except ValueError:
        pass
    cnt+=1
```

mas para grande volume de dados laços não são muito lentos?
tem outra forma de fazer isso?

Comment: eu não entendi esse código. Pq ele está fazendo o cast do valor para inteiro se depois ele substitui o valor por `nan`? Parece que o programa é mesma coisa sem a linha `int(row)`. Porque não usar `np.where` para esse propósito?

Comment: O `int(row)` está aqui apenas para testar se é possível transformar row em inteiro. Caso não seja ele gera uma exceção. O grande problema deste código, além de iterar item por item, é considerar que o índice é numérico, começa com 0 (zero) e é sequencial; o que nem sempre é verdade.

Answer (score 1):

Temos dois cenários:

1. Colunas que possuem inteiros que deveriam ser string
2. Colunas que possuem string que deveriam ser inteiros

Para o primeiro caso, por exemplo, caso o inteiro `1` tenha que se transformar na string `1`, a solução é simples: basta usar o `astype`

**Exemplo**

```
df["coluna"] = df["coluna"].astype(str)
```

Já para o segundo caso temos duas possibilidades:

a. Todos os valores que têm que ser convertidos de string para int (float) **podem** ser convertidos

b. Alguns (ou vários, ou todos) valores que têm que ser convertidos de string para int (float) **não podem** ser convertidos

Para o caso de que todos os valores podem ser convertidos, basta usar a mesma solução já descrita:

```
df["coluna"] = df["coluna"].astype(int)
```

Já para o segundo caso, veja o exemplo:

#### Criar uma função transforme para `int` ou retorne `nan`

```
import numpy as np

def to_int(row):
    try:
        return int(row)
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan
```

#### Usando a função em um dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, "a", 3, "4"]})

print(df)

   A
0  1
1  a
2  3
3  4

df["A"] = df["A"].apply(to_int)

print(df)

     A
0  1.0
1  NaN
2  3.0
3  4.0
```

**EDITADO em 10/08/2021 - motivo: comentário abaixo**

Se o 10 for inteiro, faça:

```
df["A"].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, str) else np.nan)
```

Se o 10 for tipo string, faça algo como:

```
def only_strings(row):
    try:
        int(row)
        return np.nan
    except ValueError:
        return row
```

e chame com

```
df["A"] = df["A"].apply(only_string)
```

**Fim da edição**

Comment: Acho que eu não consegui expressar na pergunta minha duvida, mas de certa forma seu comentário me ajudou muito, agora sei limpar strings em colunas numéricas. Quando falei de valores int em colunas de string na verdade foi um equivoco, o valor é um numero com tipo string. ex: em uma coluna em que o valor deveria ser sim ou não tem um numero 10.

Comment: Atualizei o post.

Comment: @LucasLopes, Eu entendi isso, fazendo o uso do apply com uma função que purga um elemento fora de contexto. Não sendo isso favor editar a pergunta esclarecendo-a.